# Check combobox on inactive tabs in tabcontrol

Tags: vb.net

I need to be able to check the selecteditem of a combobox in a tab control whether the tab is selected or not.

Currently I'm doing it based off of if the combobox is visible or not but this only checks the ones for the selected tab.

Is there a way I could get the selecteditem of the combo boxes on the 'inactive' tabs?

Each tab has a tablelayoutpanel which contains the combo boxes in question, but as mentioned above the cbo.visible is only true for the currently selected tab.

```
Private Function checkAnswers(ByVal table As TableLayoutPanel, ByVal ResponseKey As String) As Boolean
    Dim allAnswered As Boolean = True
    Dim s As String = ""
    For Each c As Control In table.Controls

        If c.GetType() Is GetType(Label) Then
            Dim lbl As Label = CType(c, Label)
            s = lbl.Text
        End If

        If TypeOf c Is ComboBox Then
            Dim cbo As ComboBox = c
            If Responses(ResponseKey)(s) = "NotAnswered" And cbo.Visible = True Then 'Combobox is showing and isnt answered
                allAnswered = False
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Return allAnswered
End Function
```

--EDIT--
The method where checkAnswers is being called:

```
Private Sub SubmitAnswers(ByRef tab As TabPage, ByRef table As TableLayoutPanel, ByRef ResponseKey As String)

    Dim instAnswer As CaisseAnswerBU = New CaisseAnswerBU

    Dim allAnswered As Boolean = True

    If Not checkAnswers(table, ResponseKey) AndAlso isEndofQuestions = True Then
        allAnswered = False
        MessageBox.Show("You must give an answer for all of " & tab.Text & "'s questions", "Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
    ElseIf checkAnswers(table, ResponseKey) AndAlso isEndofQuestions = True Then

        counter = 0

        For Each t As TabPage In ApplicantTab.TabPages
            If Not hiddenPages.Contains(t) Then
                For Each de As DictionaryEntry In Responses(ResponseKey)

                    If Responses(ResponseKey).Count <> 0 Then
                        instAnswer.applicantID = appList(counter).applicantId
                        instAnswer.applicationID = instApplication.applicationId
                        For Each dict As DictionaryEntry In questionHash
                            If de.Key = dict.Value Then
                                instAnswer.questionID = dict.Key
                            End If
                        Next

                        If de.Value = "Yes" Then
                            instAnswer.answer = True
                        Else
                            instAnswer.answer = False
                        End If
                        instAnswer.Create()
                    End If

                Next
                counter += 1
            End If
        Next
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: It only checks the comboboxes of the tab you're passing as a parameter... it would be useful to see how and when you call `checkAnswers`

Comment: It's been posted Josh